# Need help in installing 'Development Tools' using 'yum'

Tags: software-installation, yum

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS mainly for neuroimaging use. I need to install a program (see: http://dti-tk.sourceforge.net/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=SourceCode.SourceCode) which is requiring me to install 'Development Tools' from CentOS. I was directed to: https://support.eapps.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/438/55/user-guide---installing-the-centos-development-tools-gcc-flex-etc#installing-the-development-tools-using-yum where I followed the instructions on the page.

However, I find that when I enter

```
$ yum groupinstall "development tools"
There are no enabled repos.
Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

And I get `repolist: 0` when I run `yum repolist all`. When I try to enable repos with the `yum-config-manager` command, I get `You must be root to change the yum configuration.`

I'm not sure what I should do at this point? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need *"to install 'Development Tools' from CentOS"*? CentOS is a RedHat based distribution, whereas Ubuntu is Debian based. Did you actually try building it with equivalent standard tools from the Ubuntu repository?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm an Ubuntu newbie and am not confident of doing that.. I'm not sure if that is doable?

Comment: Try running  sudo yum-config-manager.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to download CentOS development tools or `yum`. If you look at the guide you'll need `cvs` and `ccmake`.

To download those, use `apt-get`. See below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cvs cmake-curses-gui
```

I found both `cvs` and `ccmake` applications by searching the cache for the repositories:

1. `sudo apt-get update` gets the latest version of the applications in the repositories. No need to do this if you've already installed the applications with the command I provided above.
2. `apt-cache search <package name>` to search for a specific application that are available in the repositories you have in your repository list.

See more with `man apt-cache` and `man apt-get`.

Comment: Just FYI: The `apt` tool can do searching: `apt search <name>`.